# Book about a pair of apes dying, spaceship gives them a shot with medicine and they thrive to become humans

Tags: story-identification, books, space, atlantis

I remember something about Atlantis in the title. The book describes a spaceship going from planet to planet to check on them. They visit a planet where there is a pair of apes dying. These apes are the very last ones and they help them to preserve the species. They give them a shot of medicine and continue to the next planet. Thousands of years later they return to see civilization blooming and I believe the ending story was somewhere in the 50s.